# How do I use the "filter" function dplyr in R to filter out the names of a winning team?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am trying to use the filter function from dplyr to produce a table with the names of the players from the winning team from each game ("season"); players are listed in order of time of death. Players that don't die have a "N/A" value. Even players that die before their team wins are still credited with a victory.

[Original dataframe; 35 seasons in total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHp6y.png)

I have tried using "filter(row_number()==n())" in order to create a new data frame with the color of the winning team for each season; that was successful. I, however, lack the knowledge of how to apply that data frame as a filter to the other data frame.

[Code for Winners data frame and attempt at using it for a filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZafo.png)
[Winners table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjFkO.png)

The issue is two-fold. You want the color to be applying appropriately to the corresponding season, but you also want to be able to list each name from the winning team (which can vary in size from 2 to 5) regardless of time of death.

I'd greatly appreciate any wisdom on this, thank you!

Comment: Please do not add data and code as screenshots, but instead edit your question to make this reproducible

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

The process is as follows:

1 - We will get the color of the team that won every season

2 - Then we will use that color to get the names of the players on that team for that season.

```
data.frame(<the data from your question>) -> data.teams

## This will get us the wining color per Season, assuming that the only NA values are from the winners:
data.teams %>%
 filter(is.na(`Death Time`)) %>%
 select(Season, `Team Color`)-> data.teams.winning

## Then we will get each team member for each Season.

left_join(data.teams.winning, data.teams, by = c('Season', 'Team Color')) -> data.players.winning
```

You can also do it with one `dplyr` chunk:

```
data.teams %>%
 filter(!is.na(`Death Time`)) %>%
 select(Season, `Team Color`) %>%
 left_join(., data.teams, by = c('Season', 'Team Color')) -> data.players.winning
```